# Converting a VM to Hyper-V, can't get past Windows Activation dialog

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, mouse, hyper-v, windows-activation

*Note: this is **not** the standard "Windows Activation Hell" question where the user gets stuck in a loop.*

Background: I keep an old VM with XP and Office 2003 on it, to support an elderly couple who became computer literate late in life and are unlikely to upgrade now. If they have a question about Excel or something, I may fire up the VM to remind myself how things are in their world, to make sure my answer will work for them.

I had the VM on an old laptop under Virtual PC. I've decided to move it to another box under Hyper-V so I can access it easily from my day-to-day workstation.

The problem: I can't get to the Windows desktop because immediately after logging on to XP, before leaving the Welcome screen, Windows pops up the Activation dialog, as it has detected the hardware change. However, although the dialog flashes several times, it never receives focus, so its buttons won't respond to keyboard input. And here's the thing: I cannot yet use the mouse, since there is no mouse support in Hyper-V until Integration Services Setup has been run, and I can't run that till I get past this point.

So this is a "Catch 22" variant of Activation Hell. I would love to say <kbd>Yes</kbd> to this dialog so that I can move forward and enable the mouse, but I need the mouse in order to say <kbd>Yes</kbd> to the dialog!

[image]

What I tried:

- Hitting keys (such as ESC, Enter, CTRL/ALT + Y or N,  SHIFT/CTRL/ALT + F1-F12, TAB, spacebar) to try and get the dialog to respond or dismiss it: no effect.
- In safe mode I can get to the desktop as the activation dialog doesn't appear, but if I try to run Integration Services Setup in safe mode, it fails with a dialog saying that one or more parts of the installation failed, and will not succeed in safe mode despite several attempts
- Similarly, if I boot in safe mode and try to activate Windows from the command line, it tells me activation can't be done in safe mode.

**EDIT** Note that keyboard input itself doesn't appear to be a problem, since I have already entered my password and hit ENTER on the previous screen. It's just that this dialog doesn't have focus.

Comment: Problably the old virtuabox tools or vmware tools etc still installed so theres a conflict, try to unistall the guest and try again.

Comment: In case its relevant, and I'm not entirely sure if it is, what VM was it running before, and do you still have access to it? I'm wondering if the integration tools for the old VM host is somehow messing with hyper V

Comment: AlejandraMoreno, @JourneymanGeek, thanks, unfortunately that's not it, as I already successfully unintstalled the old integration tools from safe mode

Comment: What about Alt-Esc? That usually allows you to change focus, though I have not experienced lack of focus on this screen.

Comment: Failing that, have alook at http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/3381-how-to-fix-windows-xp-activation-after-a-windows-xp-repair - this may allow you to get going by extending the activation time.

Comment: @AFH Alt-Esc now tried, still ignored. Will now try extending activation time.

Comment: @AFH no improvement after extending activation time, it seems for hardware change it still insists on 3-day limit and offers dialog straight away.

Comment: It extended it for me after moving a VM from a Windows to a Linux host, but I always had a mouse, so I didn't encounter your problem - I did not notice whether the activation box came up in focus. I think I have run out of ideas, but I'll be glad to hear of any solution you may come up with. Did you try running integration services set-up from safe mode?

Comment: @AFH yes I tried that, see above. Now have solution though!

Comment: I inferred from your question that you had tried Alt-Tab, which is why I suggested Alt-Esc. If Alt-Tab works, I am very surprised that Alt-Esc doesn't. But I am glad you have found your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the key combinations tried, there actually is a key combination that does get a response and gives the dialog focus: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Although the dialog has the appearance of being the only window open—so that the problem doesn't present itself as a need to switch between windows—there is in fact another window open. The Welcome screen may just look like a background, but the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> key sequence works to "switch windows" back to the dialog:

[image]   
[image]

Using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, the "Windows Product Activation" dialog can be made active and will then receive keyboard input.